# Hibernate disable Query Cache

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching

Following problem:

I create a Query to display all Entries of a MYSQL Table, if I edit a Field and execute the Query again I get the same (old) Result as in the first query.

It seems that Hibernate caches the Result. I tried to disable Caching with

> query.setCachable(false)
>
> "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
>
> "cache.provider_class"
>
> "org.hibernate.cacheable"

flushing and closing the session

but nothing works

Comment: I don't understand what you tried (it's pretty unclear to throw a bunch of options like you did). Also, I'd like to see the query.

Comment: It is a on a Servlet / JSP Page

Query query = session.createQuery("from MyTable");
query.setCacheable(false);
List<MyTable> bar = query.list();

on the first Call i get the Entries of the Table, then I edit manually some fields, if i call the function again (for example by refreshing/reloading) I get the same result as before

Comment: are you saving the object after changing it? Are there transactions involved?

Comment: okay, i forgot to commit the transaction

Answer (score 4):

I think the configuration you want is

```
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = false
```

[Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache).

Comment: this then implies that the query cache is not your problem at all

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you never saved or updated the the changed entry to hibernate? When the cache returns the wrong result that is usually an indication something else is wrong.

Comment: I changed the field in the Table manually and i committed it too

Comment: Can you update your question with the code, or at least the fragments relating to editing and updating the entry?

Answer (score 1):

it has nothing to do with 2nd or Query caches, these are already disabled by default! What probably would help in your case is to call `session.refresh(yourEntity)` so that the state of your entity would be re-read by hibernate.